# ByteArrayOutPutSteam to Byte[] not working as expected

Tags: java, bytearrayoutputstream

I need to make a `Byte[]` out of a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, but this is not working. When I log the outcome of `baos.toByteArray();` it only shows me eleven characters, no matter which file I try to upload, the log entry looks like this: `[B@544641ab`

This is the code:

```
    final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); // Stream to write to
    upload = new Upload();
    upload.setReceiver(new Upload.Receiver() {
        @Override
        public OutputStream receiveUpload(String filename, String mimeType) {

            return baos; // Return the output stream to write to
        }
    });
    upload.addSucceededListener(new Upload.SucceededListener() {
        @Override
        public void uploadSucceeded(Upload.SucceededEvent succeededEvent) {
        System.out.println ( baos.toByteArray().toString());
    }
});
```

Note: there is some Vaadin-specific code which is related to their upload-component. The upload component should provide an OutPutStream, which is correct so far.

Comment: This is what `toString()` does for byte-arrays. Thats not whats _in_ the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

`[B@544641ab` is the array type string (`[B`) combined with the identity hashcode of the byte array returned by `baos.toByteArray()`, not it's value.

### Solution

Use `Arrays.toString(baos.toByteArray())` instead of `baos.toByteArray().toString()`. You [can](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) also use `baos.toString()`.

Comment: Okay, I was not aware of this. Thank you for the answer. So .toByteArray() is doing its job like it is supposed to do I guess? I will mark the answer as soon as the website let's me do so

Comment: @TobiasKuess, yes, you're right

Comment: No it isn't. It is the result of `Object.toString()`, which concatenates the object type (`[B`) with `"@"` and the result of `System.identityHashCode()`.

Comment: @EJP, no, for `ByteArrayOutputStream` the `toString()` is overridden and returns _ buffer's contents into a string decoding bytes using the platform's default character set_ as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html)

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing the result of the  default `toString()` of a `byte[]`. If you want to print it out properly, you could use [`Arrays.toString(byte[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(byte[])):

```
System.out.println (Arrays.toString(baos.toByteArray());
```